# eclipse start up error message, how to catch it

Tags: java, eclipse

I run an eclipse Java Swing application, it works well. but I can see the error messages (red color), before the swing application run. But I can not catch it, because when the application run, inside "console", there are empty. Could anyone tell me, how can i view the error messages which were shown in "console" when I start the java application, but suddenly disappear ( is there a log file for eclipse?). Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Right click on the console > Preferences > Console buffer size
```

If you don't want any limit, uncheck the "Limit console output" checkbox. That's it. You will get all the output written to the console, without getting cleared.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but the error messages still disappear.

Comment: thanks, the error message disappear. so maybe the reason is abut my application.